# How to create MD5 hash in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, hash, md5

I want to create a MD5 hash code in Qt.

**My code :**

```
QString queryStr;
queryStr = QString("%1")
.arg(QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(ui->txtPassword->text(),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex()));
```

but my code does not work!
`hash` method does not work in **Qt**!

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text()` returns `QString`, `QCryptographicHash::hash` requires `QByteArray` and there is no implicit conversion, so you should do this by yourself. Use something like this:

```
QString queryStr;

ui->lineEdit_2->setText("hash");
queryStr = QString("%1").arg(QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(ui->lineEdit_2->text().toUtf8(),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex()));
qDebug()<< queryStr;
```

In the documentation you can see another mrthods which returns `QByteArray`. Choose the best for you.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html

Answer (score 0):

I used of `toStdString().c_str()` to casting from `QString` to `const char*` in `static QByteArray hash(const QByteArray &data, Algorithm method);` method as bellow :

```
QString queryStr;
    queryStr = QString("%1")
            .arg(QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(ui->txtPassword->text().toStdString().c_str(),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex()));
```