# Getting Sha1 hash from QString

Tags: c++, qt, hash, qstring

In my Qt5.6.1 program, I have to get a Sha-1 hash from QString, but I get incorrect result. I'm trying to use QCryptographicHash library.

```
QString str = "ABCDEFGH";    
QString hash = QString::fromStdString(QCryptographicHash::hash(str.toStdString().c_str(), QCryptographicHash::Sha1).toStdString());
// hash == "?^??[?\u0000??v??\u0015??.b??v"
```

What should I change in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this answer will be useful for you it is for md5
[How to create MD5 hash in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823709/how-to-create-md5-hash-in-qt)

instead of str.toStdString().c_str() try using  str.toUtf8()
like this form the previous answer

```
QString hash = QString("%1").arg(QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(str.toUtf8(),QCryptographicHash::Sha1).toHex()))
```